# why EF can't translate Int32.Pars(...?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Why EF can't translate `Int32.Parse` in `where` condition section?

For example below code has error :

```
var query = (from list in dbContext.Packages
                             where list.Id == Int32.Parse(Request["Id"].ToString())
                             select list).FirstOrDefault();
```

I solved this problem :

```
Int32 ID = Int32.Parse(Request["Id"].ToString());
 var query = (from list in dbContext.Packages
                             where list.Id == ID
                             select list).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the query is simply an Expression that gets translated into SQL.

EF doens't know how to translate `Int32.Parse` into an equivalent SQL statement, so it fails.

Comment: in sql there is not way to convert string to integer?

Comment: There is, but it wouldn't make any sense. Your query would get translated to a constant string being cast to an Integer. Also you are accessing the Request object which may or may not be available when the query is executed. EF doesn't know when that is going to happen, so it will also fail there.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've solved the problem is correct.

`where list.Id == Int32.Parse(Request["Id"].ToString())`, if it would work, means to send `Request` to the database, have the database extract `["Id"]`, and then call `ToString()` and `Int32.Parse()`.

`Int32 ID = Int32.Parse(Request["Id"].ToString());` is performed on the client. You then get an integer value, and only that integer value is sent to the database.